# CSS/Javascript-based image selector

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery

So forgive me, I'm just starting learning Javascript, I don't even know if this is possible.  I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="topspace">
    <div id="picholder" class="pic1">
        <div class="picsel" id="picsel1" onclick="imgSel(1)"></div>
        <div class="picsel" id="picsel2" onclick="imgSel(2)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And so what I want to accomplish is by clicking on one of the "picsel" divs (they appear as little squares at the bottom of the picholder div) I can change the backgroundImage used in picholder by changing the class associated with the picholder div.  My Javascript appears as such:

```
function imgSel(n) {
var id1 = "pic" + n;
var id2 = "picsel" + n;

// 'zero out' all the picsel boxes to their default color
document.getElementByClass('picsel').style.backgroundColor="#333";
// change the background-image for picholder
document.getElementById('picholder').style.className=id1;
// change the picsel box that was clicked to white
document.getElementById(id2).style.backgroundColor="#FFF";
}
```

And my CSS appears as such:

```
#picholder {width:798px; height:340px; border:1px solid #333; background-color:#333;}
.picsel {width:8px; height:8px; background-color:#333; border:1px solid #333; margin-left:4px; top:340px; position:relative; float:left;}
.picsel:hover {cursor:pointer; background-color:#888;}
.pic1 {background-image:url('data/main001.jpg');}
.pic2 {background-image:url('data/main002.jpg');}
```

I've run an Alert on it and the variables are being added right, so I guess what I'm wondering is, is it possible to change the className (or is that even a command?).  At this point I'm thinking I can't assign a variable to the className=var or getElementById(var), but...well...have at it.

It's currently running at http://www.mdw-art.com/, but in an HTML-based version that doesn't indicate which square is currently being displayed.  So I basically want it to do that, but I'm trying to get the boxes to indicate which one is currently displayed and get the code out of the HTML (because I want to apply this same concept to other galleries later).

Comment: What you have should work if you replace `document.getElementById('picholder').style.className` with `document.getElementById('picholder').className` - className is an attribute of the element object itself, not the style.

Comment: I've tried this.  Should it be .className=id1;, .className="id1"; or some other iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, add a class name to the selected item and allow the CSS of that class do the work for you instead of changing the inline style with JavaScript. That way you can just remove the class name from the element to un-do the selection.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  They all have class names assigned.  The reason why I'm trying to change the style via Javacsript is because I want the divs you click on not only to change the image but to also indicate which one is currently selected.

Comment: You can have multiple class names. Create one called "active" with the  visual properties you want (in your stylesheet). Add it to the element when it is clicked.

Comment: I highly suggest you look into using jQuery - it's an enhancement for JavaScript that makes this a whole lot easier and shorter: $('#picsel').addClass('active')

Comment: Okay, you've converted me.  I'm now a huge fan of jQuery.  What I did is left the existing onclick for the buttons control the image, then used jQuery to change the button that's active.  I'm gonna edit the post to show the code, thanks a bunch.

Comment: Great - the fun is just starting. Here's a fun trick: onclick="imgSel(this)" then in the function you can get $(this).id then you can parse out the target without passing any parameters at all.

Comment: After that, you can leave out the onclick and hook up the event at run-time: $('.picsel').click(function() {... your code ...}); the goal is to have clean HTML and unobtrusive javascript + css.

Comment: Alright, I'll check that out later.  Right now my goal is just to finish the site, haha.  It's my personal site so I have the fortune that I can take as long as I want on it and do whatever I want to it.  I've got an end goal for what I want it to look like and do, and I'm sure I could go just download a pre-made gallery, but where's the fun in that?

Answer (score 0):

try `.className` instead of `.style.className`

Comment: So now I have this:  document.getElementById('picholder').className=id1; and it still isn't working.  Is the variable typed correctly, or do I need quotes around it?

Comment: The example page isn't running this code, it's running <div class="picsel" id="picsel1" onclick="document.getElementById('picholder').className='pic1'"></div> and doing it with HTML/CSS only

Comment: either upload your new code  then, or set up a jsFiddle so we can see

Comment: OK, so it's throwing an error on this line `document.getElementByClass('picsel').style.backgroundColor="#333";` getElementByClass doesn't exist, you may need to consider using jQuery for that, or find another way of selecting this element. If you take that line out, it will work.

Comment: Oooh, okay...let me try switching things around.